# how to display product description in custom category page at woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have generated a custom category page in woocommerce, the products are showing successfully under the category but the descriptions do not display on the individual products.

Please help me in this regards.

Comment: Do you have any code for the custom category page and individual product pages you've created? Might be some missing or mis-typed code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this in your custom template page

```
<?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt ) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this line where you want to display product description** -

```
<?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt ); ?>
```

Or

Add this action hook in **function.php** file -

```
<?php add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 5); ?>
```